# Reset a counter after another one is increased

Tags: counters

I have the following piece of code that implements 2 counters. Currently both counters are increased equally but I would like the second to reset every time the first one is increased automatically.

Currently the counter works like this:

00001.001

00002.002

00003.003

I want it to work like this:

00001.0001

00001.0002

00001.0003

00002.0001

00002.0002

00002.0003

00003.0001

00003.0002

00003.0003

Also I don't know if there is a better implementation besides the two counters placed side by side with a dot in between, but if there is I would like you to mention it.

I would like to mention that the code for the counters in not mine. It was submitted as an answer in a question of mine in here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{Counter}

\newcommand{\Counter}
{%
  \textbf
  {%
    \ifnum\value{Counter}<10000 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{Counter}<1000 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{Counter}<100 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{Counter}<10 0\fi
    \arabic{Counter}%
  }%
}

\newcounter{InCounter}

\newcommand{\InCounter}
{%
  \textbf
  {%
    \ifnum\value{InCounter}<100 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{InCounter}<10 0\fi
    \arabic{InCounter}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\Num}
{
    \refstepcounter{Counter}\Counter.\refstepcounter{InCounter}\InCounter
}


\begin{document}

\Num

Text

\Num

Text

\Num 

Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't you add something to reset `InCounter` in the definition of the command `\Counter`?

Comment: @anderstood I don't know. :/

Comment: Which counter should be reset? What is the current implementation? That is, what does `\Counter` and `\InCounter` represent?

Comment: Well, every occurrence of `\Num` would step both counters; if you reset `InCounter` when `Counter` is stepped, the end result would be always getting 1 as the value of `InCounter`: not really useful, is it? Could you provide a better example of use?

Comment: @egreg Sure but I don't really understand what example you want. :/

Comment: @Adam I can't understand what you're about; can you describe your aim?

Comment: @egreg I see. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the second counter as bound to the first one and set properly its representation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{maincounter}
\newcounter{childcounter}[maincounter]

\renewcommand{\themaincounter}{%
  \ifnum\value{maincounter}<10000 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{maincounter}<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{maincounter}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{maincounter}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{maincounter}%
}
\renewcommand{\thechildcounter}{%
  \themaincounter.%
  \ifnum\value{childcounter}<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{childcounter}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{childcounter}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{childcounter}
}

\newcommand{\stepmain}{\stepcounter{maincounter}}
\newcommand{\stepchild}{\refstepcounter{childcounter}}
\newcommand{\num}{\stepchild\thechildcounter}

\begin{document}

\stepmain

\num

\num

\num

\stepmain

\num

\num

\stepmain

\num

\num

\end{document}
```

At each `\stepmain` the main counter is stepped and the child counter is reset; `\num` will just step the child counter and print the value. I use `\refstepcounter` here so `\label` will point to the correct value.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The standard way is like this:

```
\newcounter {secondcounter} [firstcounter]
```

and `secondcounter` will automatically reset every time `firstcounter` is increased.

Comment: It doesn't work. It only increases the second counter.

Comment: Did you try the standard way? `\newcounter {second} [first]`

Comment: You should add the qualifier that `secondcounter` is reset only if `firstcounter` is incremented via `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter`. An operation such as `\addtocounter{firstcounter}{1}` does not reset `secondcounter`.